# Need help starting to build my own hash table

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable

I'm learning about hash tables, trying to understand how they work.  I'd like to make a rather simple hash table with separate chaining (using lists in an array).  I have a few questions:

1. Assuming the keys can be of any type, I would require the user to implement the hashing function, right?  Can this be avoided?
2. The user also needs to supply the length of the array that contains the lists (for collisions) at initialisation, correct? Can this be avoided?

If you have any other tips, or maybe some clear code samples in C++ of a hash table I would be thankful.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, yes, you would need the client to specify the hash function, since if you are writing a generic hash table and are operating on an arbitrary type T, you can't know how to hash it in a way that is semantically meaningful.  You can do this by parameterizing the class on both the type of the elements being stored and the hash function.  For example:

```
template <typename T, typename Hash = std::hash<T>>
    class MyHashTable {
    /* ... */
}
```

Here, you can use default arguments with the templates to select the default hash function unless the user specifies otherwise.

While the client typically can specify the initial size of the table, it's not required.  You could make an educated guess about the number of buckets (say, initially use 17 buckets), growing the table as the load factor increases.  This is similar, say, to how `std::vector` works: the implementation can pick a default size, but if the client either explicitly asks for a presized vector or calls `reserve`, the implementation takes the hint from the user.  For example, you could have a constructor of the form

```
template <typename T, typename Hash = std::hash<T>>
    class MyHashTable {
public:
    MyHashTable(unsigned numBuckets = 17);
}
```

This way, the client can just construct a hash table with a default number of buckets, or if they have a sense of the number of buckets they'd like they can specify it as a parameter.  However, you might also want to hide the buckets as a detail and just have the client specify how many elements they're expecting to put into the table, then have your class do a computation behind the scenes for this.  This makes it easier to switch implementations behind-the-scenes, so that if you want to use something like a dynamic perfect hash table instead of chained hashing the class can handle the complexity of computing an initial size.

As for code examples, I'm not sure how to provide any without giving away a lot of the complexity involved in building the hash table. :-)  If there's a specific piece of code you're interested in and are having trouble writing on your own, feel free to post it as a separate question so that you can get more targeted feedback.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Look at various implementations of hashing algorithms. There are many available. You can have the hash storage be variable if you want. It's up to you. With most hashing algorithms, collisions can be possible. Keep this in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses the question.  If you're building your own hash table, then you probably want the client to provide the hashing algorithm, since you probably won't know in advance what the type stored is.  Also, since this is C++, you could just use `std::hash` to do the hashing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to learn about hash tables I suggest you to start with the most simple ones wich is the linear chaining hash tables

Here you consider an fixed size array of pointers(pointers to type item defined by you) where your items will be stored,consider also having some counters, one to keep track of the length of the array and another one to keep track of the number of items added to the table until a certain moment

you could use a macro to define the function of adding items to the hash table like this

```
 h(k) = k % M
```

where k is the index(key) of the item to be added and M is a prime number rappresenting the size of the array of pointers (eg 13, 29, 41, 543) and h(k) will give you the position where the item is going to be inserted.

The reason you should consider using an fixed size array of pointers is because this way you have

```
 O(n)
```

cost.

Therefore starting from this simple function you can then modify it and consider implementing some more complex ones like open adressing, linear probing, quadratic probing and double hashing

As for the user requested input regarding the number of items i totally agree with what templatetypedef said earlier